# Paperclip: width is 100%, height is 60% of width

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, paperclip

How would I write a Paperclip style to keep the width of the uploaded image at 100% but crop only the height to 60% of the width?

Something like this:

```
has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :cropped => "100%x[60% of height]" }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
has_attached_file :image, :styles => after_save :save_image_dimensions

def save_image_dimensions
  geo = Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(image.path)
  self.image_height = (geo.height.to_i * 60)/100 
end
```

If you have problem on extract dimension From below you can get a good help

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Extracting-image-dimensions

Please look into this link for cropping images using paperclip

http://viget.com/extend/manual-cropping-with-paperclip

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
has_attached_file :image, :styles => { 
                      :original  => "100x60>",
                      :thumb => Proc.new { |instance| instance.resize }
                    }
  #### End Paperclip ####

  def resize     
     geo = Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(image.to_file(:original))
     height = (geo.width.to_i * 60)/100
     width = geo.width     
     "#{width.round}x#{height.round}!"    
  end
```

Hope this could help you

Comment: I get a `NameError` for `undefined local variable or method 'image'`. Tried changing `image` to what I use for image names, still nothing. Any advice?

Comment: On new saves, I needed to use `main_image.queued_for_write[:original].path` as the parameter instead.